# Python pack string as ascii hex value

Tags: python, struct, pack

I have a problem (maybe in understanding) with the struct module and the pack method. I need to pack a message to communicate with a sensor. One value of this message is the ascii representation of an integer (in this case "0" and "3"), which is 48 and 51. The sensor only accepts hex values (in this case 30 and 33). But when I use `pack('BB',48,51)` it gives me '\x0003' back but I need '\x30\x33'. Is there a way to convert these two chars to "hex-binaries"?

Comment: It doesn't give you `\x0003`. It gives you `'03'` because Python is displaying the byte values as ASCII characters where possible. They are still the bytes with values `\x30` and `\x33`.

Comment: You'll have to be clearer in what you mean by the sensor only accepting hex values, because then you'd have to send the literal `3`, `0` `3` and `3` ASCII characters (bytes 0x33, 0x30, 0x33 and 0x33).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters♦ I thought if python displays the byte values as \x03 it also sends \x03. My understanding of how python displays and handles the byte strings was wrong, next time I will be more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'\x30\x33'` is the same as `'03'`

```
>>> import struct
>>> print struct.pack('BB', 48, 51)
03
>>> print '\x30\x33'
03
>>> '\x30\x33' == '03'
True
```

`'\x30\x33'` and `'03'` are different representation of the same thing.
`'\x30\x33'` is defined by their hex values and `'03'` by ASCII characters.

In the end both of them are an array of two bytes 48 (0x30) and 51 (0x33).

> The sensor only accepts hex values

Sensor only accepts bytes, it depends how you need to encode the value.
Do you need to send a number 3 or a string "03"?

If it's a number you will need to send `"\x03"` or `pack("B", 3)`.
If it's a string you just need to send `"03"`.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed description. I found out, that my error wasn't related to the byte string at all but to a bit-shift which I applied before the packing. (put parentheses around your bit-shifts!)

Answer (score -1):

If it's not nessesary to use pack, you can use something like this:

```
'\\'+hex(48)[1:]
```